# Discord.js : How to make a bot DM all members in a server?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to DM all members in my server, but i have no clue on how to go about this. if you can help I'd appreciate it!

**Discord.js v12**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => { // Looping through each member of the guild.
    // Trying to send a message to the member.
    // This method might fail because of the member's privacy settings, so we're using .catch
    member.send("Hello, this is my message!").catch(e => console.error(`Couldn't DM member ${member.user.tag}`));
});
```